# tikzpicture side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, sidebyside

How can I put this graph side by side

```
 \begin{figure}[htb]

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.5\linewidth,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
            ]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
            {(2-x^2-y^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Paraboloide de revolución}

    \label{pare}

\end{figure}

\hfill

    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.5\linewidth,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
            ]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
            {(x*y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \label{pard}

    \caption{Paraboloide hiperbólico}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the two pictures in the same `figure` environment. Use `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.95\linewidth,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
  ]
  \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]{(2-x^2-y^2)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Paraboloide de revolución}\label{pare}

\end{minipage}\hfill %               <--- no blank line here
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=0.95\linewidth,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
  ]
  \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]{(x*y)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Paraboloide hiperbólico}\label{pard}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the `figure label` centered under the figure?

Comment: @alper The minipages are used in order to have *two* captions.

Comment: I was trying to adapt your solution into another tikzpicture figures I have. Both captions  does not centered under the both figure. Can I ask a new question regarding to this?

Comment: @alper Yes, but give details, please.

Comment: Please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687640/how-can-i-center-labels-under-tikzpicture-using-minipage  ; thanks for your valuable help.