# How can I force to center labels under tikzpicture using minipage?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, sidebyside

I am trying to adapt solution ([tikzpicture side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/635257/127048)) into another tikzpicture figures I have. Both captions does not centered under the both figure.

The basic code is as follow:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\sisetup{
    round-mode          = places,
    round-precision     = 2,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                enlarge x limits=0.80,
                x tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                ylabel={Average Time (\unit{\second})},
                width = 6cm, height = 5cm,
                % width = 15.4cm, height = 10.7cm,
                grid=both,
                legend style={
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    cells={anchor=west}
                },
                legend pos=north west,
                symbolic x coords={Workload 1},
                xtick=data,
                tick label style={font=\normalsize},
                ybar,
                bar width = .8cm
                ]
                \addplot coordinates {(Workload 1, 9) (Workload 2, 13)};
                \addplot coordinates {(Workload 1, 9) (Workload 2, 13)};
                \legend{A,B}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Paraboloide de}\label{pare}
    \end{minipage}\hfill %               <--- no blank line here
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                enlarge x limits=0.80,
                % enlarge y limits=0.05,
                x tick label style={
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
                ylabel={Average Time (\unit{\second})},
                width = 6cm, height = 5cm,
                % width = 15.4cm, height = 10.7cm,
                grid=both,
                legend style={
                    font=\scriptsize,
                    cells={anchor=west}
                },
                legend pos=north west,
                symbolic x coords={Workload 2},
                xtick=data,
                tick label style={font=\normalsize},
                ybar,
                bar width = .8cm
                ]
                \addplot coordinates {(Workload 1, 10) (Workload 2, 12)};
                \addplot coordinates {(Workload 1, 10) (Workload 2, 12)};
                \legend{A,B}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Paraboloide }\label{pard}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

output is as follow:

[image]

Labels for the both figure look kind of leftly aligned. Is it possible to force to center labels under each figure?

Comment: The TikZ picture includes the *y* axis and its description not only the box. The caption is centered across the whole width of the minipage. The TikZ picture is wider than the minipage (see the overfull hbox messages). I'd use `width=\linewidth` instead of `6cm` and also `.48\textwidth` for the width of the `minipage`s.

Comment: I have made the changes you mentioned but the label still is not perfectly centered not sure why :-(